# Ajax filtering a Drupal7 View

Tags: 7, views

I have a View where i would like to expose filters to permit the user to customize the view output. I know i can use exposed filters but, instead of a drop down (or checkbox/radiobutton of exposed filters) i want to put a list of DIV or LI that, when clicked, can update the view output through ajax. In which way is it possible using Views 3 and Drupal 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install [Better Exposed filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) in D7, edit the view and in the advanced fieldset change the exposed form style to "Better exposed filters", then in the settings for this you can choose how you want to display the filters, choose "Links". Also check the boxes for "Autosubmit" and "Hide submit button"

Answer (score 2):

Views allow to use Ajax fro filtering out of the box - edit view, click on "Advanced" link and in "Use AJAX" option select "Yes"

If you want to theme checkbox/radiobutton as div - you can use JQuery. There are a lot of libraries that can do such themisation.

Answer (score 2):

Better Exposed Filters doesn't currently support ajax filtering on the links view.  I posted how I was able to accomplish this, without BEF, in https://drupal.org/node/1111712#comment-7370826.